# Wordpress Defined Memory Limit

Tags: memory, limit

Running a dedicated managed server with 2 GIGS of RAM. How much memory can I define in `wp-config.php`

Currently I have

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

I suspect a plugin that resizes images when they are being uploaded, that might cause the server to crash, but I am not sure yet.

How can I allocate more memory for this plugin to operate?

Many thanks
Andy

Comment: Instead of `256M` write `2048M` ? Memory limits above 256 only work after WP ver 3.2 for the `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try one (or more) of the below methods to increase the memory allicated by PHP. First try increasing the limit to 64MB, and if that fails use 96M.

---

You can define the [`WP_MEMORY_LIMIT`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) constant in `wp-config.php`:

**Increase PHP Memory to 64MB**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

**Increase PHP Memory to 96MB**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
```

---

You can also change the setting in your `.htaccess` file:

**Increase PHP Memory to 64MB**

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

**Increase PHP Memory to 96MB**

```
php_value memory_limit 96M
```

---

You can add a line to `wp-config.php` telling PHP to increase the memory limit:

**Increase PHP Memory to 64MB**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
```

**Increase PHP Memory to 96MB**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','96M');
```

This is not the most preferred method, and you should try the other methods first.

Comment: I agree with everything except using ini_set(), do it in your php.ini or .htaccess, never in your code!

Comment: ok, I am not a server expert but i am just moving to a dedicated managed server with 12 GIGS of RAM.... What setting should I put in wordpress and where it's best to do that? :)

Comment: @theMojoWill I agree that the other methods are preferable - however, not everyone has access to .htaccess or php.ini.

Comment: If you don't have access to .htaccess or php.ini then I doubt that the host will allow ini_set()

Answer (score 1):

256MB is a pretty decent limit to start with. Bear in mind that PHP's memory limit is different from PHP's max file upload size.

```
ini_set( 'memory_limit', '128M');
ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '10M' );
ini_set( 'post_max_size', '10M');
```

- `memory_limit` is how much memory a PHP process can use **at one time**. This includes the script processing, handling operations, etc. Generally, if you have to take this value really high, you're doing something very wrong. Most servers can probably survive on `256MB` with no problem.
- `upload_max_size` is the maximum file size a file uploaded and passed to PHP may be. This, in-turn, determines the WordPress maximum file size.
- `post_max_size` sets the max size of post data allowed. From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

> This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

Understanding these directives and their differences will help you better configure your server to address the problems you are solving. Good luck!